# Animated SVG path doesn't show up in Firefox when hidden initially

Tags: javascript, firefox, animation, svg

I'm trying to debug why this piece of animating SVG isn't working in Firefox.

Test case & code here: http://jsbin.com/AYICOwE/18/edit

I'm changing the `stroke-dasharray` attribute on a `<path>`-element inside of an inline `<svg>` graphic, to progressively draw a dashed line. Since I don't want the path to show before I animate it, I set the `stroke`-attribute to `none` initially (have also tried to set it to a transparent color), and then re-set it when the animation runs.

The progressive drawing of the dashes works everywhere when the line initially has a visible `stroke`, but as soon as it doesn't, Firefox doesn't show anything at all. When the line is initially shown, I can still animate it, hide it (by setting `stroke` to `none`) and show it again etc.

Toggling CSS properties in the inspector (causing the element to repaint) afterwards snaps it into view.

Browser bug, or something I'm doing wrong/stupidly? Workaround ideas?

Comment: Just commenting to say that this was the 6 millionth post on SO, congrats!

Comment: @JamieTaylor Woo! Do I get a prize? :-)

Comment: Please record your issue [by clicking here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG)